# How to get data from grid and download them like .csv file in ExtJS 4.2

Tags: download, extjs4.2, export-to-csv

I have a Ext.grid.Panel and I fill it with store that is populated from database. And there is an export button. When the user click on the Export button, I want the data from grid should start downloading like .csv file

Answer (score 2):

The best solution to creating any type of file (Excel, CSV, PDF, whatever) is going to be leveraging your application server to create and serve up the file for download. There are literally thousands of libraries across most of the popular server-side languages that can create just about any kind of file that you'd want to create.

So ultimately this has nothing to do with Ext JS or even JavaScript. All that your export button should do, IMO, is to create an AJAX request which triggers the process (query, transform results, publish to a correct content type, stream to browser) that will be needed to generate the content from your application server technology.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes you can't leverage an application server such as when your back end is a micro controller or you can't get the back end people to make the change.

I've not used this, but it looks nice:
http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?136598-Export-store-to-Excel